# Unable to use .each to for hash value operation

Tags: ruby

Why can't I combine `newer` to `older`?

```
def update_inventory(older, newer)
  newer.each {|x, y| older[x] += y}
end

update_inventory({rubies: 10, emeralds: 14, diamonds: 2}, {emeralds: 27, moonstones: 5})
```

> undefined method +' for `nil:NilClass`
>   (repl):2:in block in `update_inventory`
>   (repl):2:in `each`
>   (repl):2:in `update_inventory`
>   (repl):5:in `<main>`

Comment: Because there's a nil like it says?

Comment: The `older` hash does not contain the key: `:moonstones`. So `older[:moonstones] == nil`. You cannot add to `nil`. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: What result are you *expecting* to see here? I can help "fix" the code, but not without knowing the desired behaviour!

Comment: this approach is certainly too simplistic to properly handle all cases. if i was you i'd check the underlying concept and try to come up with a more appropriate way of representing the inventory, rather than using hashes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work as expected because `older` does not contain all keys from `newer`.

`newer` consists of two key-value pairs: `{emeralds: 27, moonstones: 5}` so `newer.each` will invoke the block `{ |x, y| ... }` twice:

1. on the 1st iteration, `x` is `:emeralds` and `y` is `27` which works just fine because `older` has a value for `:emeralds`:

   ```
   older[:emeralds]       #=> 14
   older[:emeralds] += 27 #=> 41
   ```
2. on the 2nd iteration, `x` is `:moonstones` and `y` is `5`, so you get:

   ```
   older[:moonstones]      #=> nil
   older[:moonstones] += 5 #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
   ```

   The error is caused because Ruby tries to calculate `nil + 5` and `nil` doesn't have a `+` method (hence *"undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass"*).

---

To fix this, you *could* add a condition that checks whether the key exists. But there's a simpler way: [`Hash#update`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) does exactly what you need:

```
def update_inventory(older, newer)
  older.update(newer) { |_, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
end
```

It will copy the key-value pairs from `newer` into `older`. If a key exists in both hashes, the block will be called to determine the new value.

```
older = {rubies: 10, emeralds: 14, diamonds: 2}
newer = {emeralds: 27, moonstones: 5})

older.update(newer) { |_, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
#=> {:rubies=>10, :emeralds=>41, :diamonds=>2, :moonstones=>5}
```